open62541 cannot add a node with numeric type, namespace≠0 and identifier=0
According to the OPC UA specification, it seems permissible to create a node with numeritc type, namespace ≠ 0 and identifier = 0. However, in open62541, if I specify a numeric type with identifier = 0, it gets converted to a random number as following link.
https://www.open62541.org/doc/v1.4.0/server.html#node-addition-and-deletion
When I actually implemented adding a node with a numeric type where namespace ≠ 0 and identifier = 0 (using UA_Server_addObjectNode or UA_Server_addVariableNode in open62541), it resulted in a node with identifier = 50510 being created. Upon tracing with gdb, it appears that internally the function UA_NodeMap_insertNode is called, which seems to have a hardcoded conversion for identifier = 0.
Is there a way in open62541 to create a numeric type node with namespace≠0 and identifier = 0?
